# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '20' in .top10_month .periods

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have strange error, and don't understand why!
May be somebody can help me and tell, what wrong is here.

```
Page.contentSort = function () {
    var $eachblocks = (".top10_month .periods");
    var $blockhead = $(".block-head__link");
    $blockhead.on("click", function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var sortvalue = $this.attr("data-date");
        e.preventDefault();
        $this.parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
        this.className += " active";
        $.each($eachblocks, function () {
            if ($eachblocks.attr("data-period") === $(".block-head__link.active").attr("data-date")) {
                $(this).addclass("active");
            } else {
                $eachblocks.removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `$`, So instead of

```
var $eachblocks = (".top10_month .periods");
```

Use

```
var $eachblocks = $(".top10_month .periods");
```

Additionally, You should use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

So instead of

```
var sortvalue = $this.attr("data-date");
```

use

```
var sortvalue = $this.data("date");
```

You should go thorough [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get data attribute like following, instead of using `.attr();`

```
$this.data("date");
$this.data("period");
```